# Why does margin: auto not center a button element inside a li element?

Tags: html, css

Why does the `margin: auto` not center the button inside an `li` in this example? I can however use `text-align: center` to center it. Why does this happen?
I even tried to insert the button inside a container but this still seems to not work.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

textarea {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button {
  background: blue;
  border: solid thin;
  display: block;
  padding: auto;
}

button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="msg">Message:</label>
      <textarea name="user_message" id="msg" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li class="button">
      <button type="button">Button</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: @AmirDanish I tried that too

Comment: because in this case, it is a text element not a block element. margin auto works only for block elements.

Comment: @tacoshy thank you. Using display:block on button works as expected

Comment: just change the display: block; to display: flex; in .button

Comment: `li {display: table; margin: auto;}` - only for first `li`

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block`in button and  `text-align:center;` in  li tag:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

textarea {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button {
  background: blue;
  border: solid thin;
  display: block;
  padding: auto;
  text-align:center;/*Css Added*/
}

button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;/*Css Added*/
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="msg">Message:</label>
            <textarea name="user_message" id="msg" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li class="button">
            <button type="button">Button</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `margin: auto` to center elements only works with elements with a display of `block`, however `button`s have a default display of `inline-block` which does not let you do that.

The difference between them is:

- elements with a display of block take up an entire row, you can set the width of them, and you can center them by using `margin: 0 auto`
- elements with a display of inline-block don't take up an entire row, but you can still set the width of the element, but they can't be centered by using `margin: 0 auto` - **this is the default style of the button element**
- elements with a display of inline flow inline with everything else, and you cant set the width or height of them

So we can add `display: block` to the button to sort it out.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

textarea {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button {
  background: blue;
  border: solid thin;
  display: block;
  padding: auto;
}

button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="msg">Message:</label>
      <textarea name="user_message" id="msg" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li class="button">
      <button type="button">Button</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```